# How to get third-party keyboard size in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, ios8

I've installed Swift Keyboard in my phone 5s with iOS 8.

The original method (Objective-C) to obtain the keyboard size only works with the system keyboard, for example:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
}
```

If I use Swift Keyboard... keyboardSize.height is zero. 
How to get third-party keyboard size in iOS 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever find correct solution for this? The answer below is not working with my case. I'm already using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to get the KB rect.

Answer (score 8):

I think that's because you're getting the size before the keyboard has actually been displayed.

Try replacing:

```
objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
```

With:

```
objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
```

This is working for me with SwiftKey!

Comment: This matches my own research. I've also noticed SwiftKey sending 3 events on show, with the end height set to 0, then the height of the keyboard, then the height of the keyboard + autocomplete area. My code was not expecting 3 UIKeyboardWillShowNotification events in a row with different heights, so needed some adjustment.

Comment: This isn't working for me, I'm already using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to get the KB's rect. Any other way?